# error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to capture Kafka events (which I am getting in serialised form) using sparkStreaming in Scala.

Here is my code-snippet:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val topics=Set("<topic-name>")
val brokers="<some-list>"
val groupId="spark-streaming-test"

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> groupId,
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val messages: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println(rdd.toDF())
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am getting error message as:
Error:(59, 19) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]] println(rdd.toDF())

Answer (score 1):

`toDF` comes through `DatasetHolder`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits

I haven't replicated it but my guess is that there's no encoder for `ConsumerRecord[String, String]` so you can either provide one or map it first to something for which an `Encoder` can be derived (case class or a primitive)

also println within `foreachRDD` will probably not act the way you want due to the distributed nature of spark

Comment: Thanks. As I am new to this therefore, couldn't understand much. 
I replaced the code and try directly printing RDD as below:
    messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      println("Messages: " + rdd)
    }
it ran successfully giving output as:
Messages: KafkaRDD[1] at createDirectStream at kafkaStream.scala:51

What I want to see is the data behind these RDDs.

Comment: well for a possibly infinite stream that's a bit tricky. you could tranform the data to a human readable format and save to to e.g. HDFS and look at it there. `println` is very seldomly useful in spark unless your materialize the data to the driver node.

How to extract the info into a readable format depends on how your kafkaconfic looks like but most likely you'll want to create some case class with the fields your interested in and tranform the ConsumerRecord into that case class

Generall I'd recommend looking at how spark and RDDs work under the hood and how it distributes computation

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code as:
messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val dataFrame = rdd.map(row => row.value()).toDF()
      dataFrame.show(10)
    }

And got the result as:

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|��srHcom.egenc...|
|��srPcom.egenc...|
|��srPcom.egenc...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

It is working now. Just need to deserialise this data to make it readable. 
I used value.deserializer in the code, but it is not working.
Do you have any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: `val df = messages.map( _.value )` then anything is the same.